# How to merge elements in list, how to compare 2 elements in list

Tags: python, list

I am new to programming, having a question:

I have two lists:

```
list = ["ich", "du", "etc", "."]
abbr = ["etc.", "U.S"]
```

I need to identify abbreviations in the first list using the list of given abbreviations in the second. 
I need to go through elements of first list and if element of the list and next element of the list together are contained in abbreviation list, then merge both of them to get list like,

```
list = ["ich", "du", "etc."]
```

My problem is how to merge both of them and how to join element to the next element. How I can use here next element instead of "."

```
for elem in list:
if ''.join((elem, ".")) in abbr:
```

Comment: Had a misunderstood, sorry my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can zip the sequence of the list and itself with one index apart by padded by an extra empty string in the end, so that you can iterate through the sequence in pairs, merge the pair when they are found in the abbreviation list (which is more efficient as a set) and skip the next pair since the next string has already been merged:

```
lst = ["ich", "du", "etc", "."]
abbr = {"etc.", "U.S"}
pairs = zip(lst, lst[1:] + [''])
merged = []
for a, b in pairs:
    ab = a + b
    if ab in abbr:
        merged.append(ab)
        next(pairs, None)
    else:
        merged.append(a)
print(merged)
```

This outputs:

```
['ich', 'du', 'etc.']
```

Note that if you are using Python 2.7 or earlier versions, you can initialize `pairs` with the `iter` function added instead:

```
pairs = iter(zip(lst, lst[1:] + ['']))
```

Comment: This wouldnt work in python2 because zip produces a list in python2

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for Python 2 then.

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this:

```
for elem, nextelem in zip(list,list[1:]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
lst = ["ich", "du", "etc", "."]
abbr = ["etc.", "U.S"]

for elem, nextelem in zip(lst[:-1],lst[1:]):
  if elem + nextelem in abbr:
    lst.remove(elem)
    lst.remove(nextelem)
    lst.append(elem + nextelem)

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
['ich', 'du', 'etc.']
```

Comment: Using the `remove` method is not only inefficient (as it requires O(n)) but also dangerous when there are several occurrences of the given value in the list (since it removes the first match it finds, which may not be the one to be merged).

Comment: @blhsing Yes agreed, that was an approach to the solution and considering no duplicate values. Your solution is definitely better.